# thymeleaf, how to display a set as a matrix

Tags: thymeleaf

I have a dynamic set, it could contain any number of images
I want to display the images as a matrix of 3 x 3
if the number of images is greater than 9 then add another matrix and so on
I am trying to do the following with thymeleaf

example 1

```
img, img, img
img, empty, empty
empty, empty, empty
```

example 2

```
img, img, img    img, img, img
img, img, img    img, img, img
img, img, img    empty, empty, empty
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would partition your `Set` into a `List` of `List`s (of length 9 each) in your controller -- you can program this yourself, or use something like `ListUtils.partition()` in Apache Commons Collections.

Then the Thymeleaf is just iterating over two lists -- the outer list is a new 3x3 matrix, and the inner list contains the elements of the matrix.